Computational Difficulty with Solving System of Equations in an Optimization Problem with 3 constraints (2 active & 1 inactive)
I was given the following problem:
Minimize: $$f = -2x + 3y^2$$
Subject to: $$g_1 = (x-1)^2 + y^2 > 1 \\g_2=(x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 4\\g_3 =x \geq 0 $$
Currently, I am trying to find a minimizer candidate using the KKT FOC.
Here, I omit $g_1$ since it isn't an active constraint, and negative $g_3$ to make the inequality less than or equal to.
$\nabla f(x,y) = <2, 6y>$ ; $\nabla g_2(x,y) = <2x - 2, 2y>$ ; $\nabla g_3(x,y) = <-1,0>$
From KKT, I get the system of equations
$$2 + (2x-2)\mu_1-\mu_2=0$$
$$6y + (2y)\mu_1 = 0$$
$$\mu_1 [(x-1)^2 + y^2] = 0$$
$$\mu_2 (-x) = 0$$
I am having a hard time solving this system of equations. Every time I try the computation, I get a different answer for the minimizer candidate $(x,y)$.

$g_1$ should be inactive because it is a strict inequality.

No, not because of that.

Let $A$ be the portion of annulus defined by these inequalities, and $\overline A=A\cup C$ its closure, where $C$ is the circle $C:(x-1)^2+y^2=1$.
For $y$ fixed, when $M=(x,y)$ varies in $\overline A$, $f(x,y)$ is minimum when $x$ is maximum, i.e. when $M$ is on the half-circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=4,x\ge1$. Therefore, the constraints $g_1$ and $g_3$ are "inactive", and we are left with the equations:
$$\color{red}{\bf-}2+2(x-1)\mu=0$$
$$6y+2y\mu= 0$$
$$\mu[(x-1)^2 + y^2\color{red}{-4}] = 0.$$
Since $\mu\ge0$, the solution is $$y=0,\quad x=3,\quad\mu=\frac12.$$

Would you please explain why g3 is inactive?

For the same reason as $g_1$: because the half circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=4,x\ge1$ is disjoint from $x=0$ as well as from $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$.

For a better understanding of "inactive", please follow the corresponding link in my answer.

I get it now. Thanks a lot!
